# How to add items to a List Control in an MFC dialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, listview, mfc

In order to have a table like:

[image]
in my MFC dialog, I have added a `List Control` to it. 
And then with `Add Variable` wizard, I have created this variable for the control:

```
public:
CListCtrl m_lstIDC_LIST1Control;
```

and then in the `OnInitDialog` function of my dialog, I have added these lines of code:

```
// TODO: Add extra initialization here
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);
//m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.SetExtendedStyle( LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS);
LVITEM lvItem;

lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
lvItem.iItem = 0;
lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
char* text = "Sandra C. Anschwitz";
wchar_t wtext[50];
mbstowcs(wtext, text, strlen(text)+1);
LPWSTR ptr = wtext;
lvItem.pszText = ptr;
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.InsertItem(&lvItem);
UpdateData(false);
```

the result that I get is:

[image]
and if I uncomment the line:

```
//m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.SetExtendedStyle( LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS);
```

the horizontal grids will not be shown either!
So what's the problem?
Why the item that I have added is not shown?
what should I do in order to create a table like the one shown in the first picture?

Answer (score 24):

First, make sure you chose the `Report` option of the `View` property of the List Control in the Resource Editor. I suspect that you are using the default `Icon` view, which is not what you want.

Then, you need to add the required columns:

```
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.InsertColumn(0, _T("Full Name"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 90);
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.InsertColumn(1, _T("Profession"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 90);
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.InsertColumn(2, _T("Fav Sport"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 90);
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.InsertColumn(3, _T("Hobby"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 90);
```

Finally, you can populate your list items simply as follows:

```
int nIndex = m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.InsertItem(0, _T("Sandra C. Anschwitz"));
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.SetItemText(nIndex, 1, _T("Singer"));
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.SetItemText(nIndex, 2, _T("Handball"));
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.SetItemText(nIndex, 3, _T("Beach"));

nIndex = m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.InsertItem(1, _T("Roger A. Miller"));
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.SetItemText(nIndex, 1, _T("Footballer"));
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.SetItemText(nIndex, 2, _T("Tennis"));
m_lstIDC_LIST1Control.SetItemText(nIndex, 3, _T("Teaching"));
```

And so on ....

Comment: Hw can we make these Each Row Clickable?

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure you've got the right kind of control... you want what (at least on Visual Studio 2008's Resource Editor) is called a List Control in the toolbox, not the List Box.